# Submit button clicked multiple times (jmeter)

Tags: testing, jmeter, automated-tests

I have a web application where there is a login page, an application submission page and a logout page. Once the submit button in the page is clicked, the button gets disabled. I created a script in jmeter for this. I' am using a ultimate thread group with 10 threads. I have a default login credentials as parameters in the login page sampler. When i run this script, first login page sample is executed 10 times, then application submission sample is executed 10 times. Here i have a doubt, how can i handle this application submission sample as in the first thread itself the submit button will be disabled. But, i get a pass scenario when this scenario is ran 10 times.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter is not like QTP/Selenium - It does not check if the button is enabled / disabled.
It sends the http request for the user action.  So you will be able to send requests again and again (unless there is a server side logic to handle this - ie user can send only one request or something like that).

But in the source code/http response , you can check if the button is disabled or not by using Regular Expression Extractor. You can build your test accordingly.